# tooltip width is hidden when mouse over on table header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, jquery-tooltip

I have a scenario to show the tooltip on mouse over, it works fine but at table header the tooltip width is hidden.
Below code is causing the issue, but i should not remove that code, please suggest how to enhance the written css code to make tooltip fully displayed. Full working sample with code: http://jsfiddle.net/8WKTj/41/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    gridviewScroll();
}); 

function gridviewScroll() {
    gridView1 = $('#GridView1').gridviewScroll({
                    width: 1545,
                    height: 500,
                    railcolor: "#F0F0F0",
                    barcolor: "#CDCDCD",
                    barhovercolor: "#606060",
                    freezesize: 3, // no of columns to lock on the left
                    arrowsize: 30,
                    headerrowcount: 1,
                    railsize: 16,
                    barsize: 8
                });
}
```

PS: If i remove the above mentioned code from my jsp file, tooltip works fine but i should not remove that code.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize hover effect before the function call. Please see the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8WKTj/44/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("span.question").hover(function () {
    $(this).append('<div class="tooltip"><p>Text goes here....</p></div>');
  }, function () {
    $("div.tooltip").remove();
  });    
gridviewScroll();
});
```

Comment: For me when tried as above tooltip is not getting displayed at all. If i place gridviewScroll() as first statement in ready function then tooltip with half width is displayed, any ideas please suggest. @Aliasgar Rajpiplawala

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it helps: http://goo.gl/mDN4CR

You can also change the tooltip text via JS